# My code doesn't work right? IF-statement multiple classes

Tags: java, class, if-statement

I am relatively new to Java and as a newbie I have trouble understanding how the code works or executes. Most often I've figured out the answer in a minute or two, sometimes in an hour or two. However, I've been stuck for two days now and I'm afraid I can't work out the problem on my own.

The programming exercise that I'm currently working on is nearly finished, save for one bit that isn't working right: method setMaxSize doesn't seem to work the way it should. I've tried to edit the method addPlayer to make a IF-statement concerning the team's max size and current size. However, the method does not add players to the list, regardless of the fact that the team list is empty at the moment. What did I do wrong? Where's my mistake? How can I get the IF-statement in addPlayer to accept new players in an empty list while checking for the maximum possible number of players in team?

I'd appreciate any feedback I can get and I apologize if it's a noobish question, but I'm really running out of patience here. Also, it's not homework: it's a programming exercise I found online from a university website I found, but I have trouble finishing it.

I'm including the two class files and the main field.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Team {
private String name;
private ArrayList<Player> list = new ArrayList<Player>();
private int maxSize;

public Team (String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public void addPlayer(Player player){
    if (list.size() <= this.maxSize){
        this.list.add(new Player(player.getName(), player.goals()));
    }
}

public void printPlayers(){
    for (Player player : list){
        System.out.println(player.toString());
    }
}

public void setMaxSize(int maxSize){
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
}

public int size(){
    return this.list.size();
}

public int goals(){
    int goalSum = 0;
    for (Player player : list){
        goalSum+=player.goals();
    }
    return goalSum;
}
}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Team barcelona = new Team("FC Barcelona");

    Player brian = new Player("Brian");
    Player pekka = new Player("Pekka", 39);
    barcelona.addPlayer(brian);
    barcelona.addPlayer(pekka);
    barcelona.addPlayer(new Player("Mikael", 1));

    System.out.println("Total goals: " + barcelona.goals());
}
}

public class Player {
private String name;
private int goal;

public Player(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public Player(String name, int goal){
    this.name = name;
    this.goal = goal;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public int goals(){
    return this.goal;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Player: " + this.name + ", goals " + this.goal;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setMaxSize` before adding players to the team.

Comment: Of course, I didn't set the value at all for some of the constructors (as per exercise instructions), you can't really go below zero. Thanks for the help, mate!

Answer (score 0):

As you have said before, you are never calling setMaxSize, so there is maxSize is initially 0. Additionally, I suggest making setters and getters for all your data fields in each class, and making each field private.

For example, you have a setter for maxSize, but not getter. It doesn't make much sense to do one but not the other, right? You create better encapsulation and allow for future changes of your code much easier this way, and again it is better practice for future projects.

Comment: This exercise is a part of an online course where you can send the ready programs for an automated check; if the program passes the tests, you gain points to unlock more programming exercises. I'm with you when it comes to creating both getters and setters (it was fully covered in one of the topics), but adding that extra getter wouldn't allow me to pass this specific exercise.